# Prevent marginfigure in memoir class from introducing new paragraph

Tags: floats, memoir, paragraphs, marginpar

The `marginfigure` environment from the memoir class seems to have a different behavior from the regular `figure` environment as it introduces a new paragraph when placed within a block of text.

Is this a desired feature?

Is there a way to leave the `marginfigure` command where it is and not have it create a new paragraph?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

My first paragraph begins here.
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
This should be in the same paragraph.

\vspace{1em}

My second paragraph begins here.
\begin{marginfigure}
\end{marginfigure}
This should be in the same paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: marginfigure introduces paragraph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't guarantee this is safe in all cases, and note the extra added `%`, but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

My first paragraph begins here.
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
This should be in the same paragraph.

\vspace{1em}

My second paragraph begins here.
{\def\par{\let\par\endgraf}\begin{marginfigure}
  weee!
\end{marginfigure}}%
This should be in the same paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it comes from the fact that `marginfigure` issues `\FloatBlock` which explictly execute `\par`

Comment: @daleif yes although sometimes issues `\clearpage` etc which would be harder to stop,:-)

Comment: I noticed that using the solution by David Carlisle, the next paragraph-break following the `marginfigure` will be disregarded. I was able to solve this by putting the whole `marginfigure` (with the new definitions) in curly brackets.

Comment: @Mathis oops I'll edit the answer:-)